# Trying to find a specific object from an array list of objects

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to make a Sokoban game(the one where the player pushes crates into diamonds).
I have worked out displaying the sprites to the screen and can move the player sprite but can get pushing part to work.

This is my movement method:

```
public void move(Direction d){ 

    char objectType;
    Objects o;
    Point p = convertPhysicalToGrid(WKSprite.getLocation());
    Point q = getLocation(p, d);

    objectType = getObjectTypeAtPoint(q);
    o = getObjectAtPoint(q);

    Point n = getLocation(q, d);


    System.out.println(objectType);
    System.out.println(o);

    if (q != null) {
        if(objectType == 'C' ){     
            System.out.println("Crate hit");
            grid[q.y][q.x] = grid[n.y][n.x];
            grid[p.y][p.x] = grid[q.y][q.x];
            grid[p.y][p.x] = null;
            o.setLocation(convertGridToPhysical(n)); 
            WKSprite.setLocation(convertGridToPhysical(q));  

        }
        else if(grid[q.y][q.x] == null){
            grid[p.y][p.x] = grid[q.y][q.x];
            grid[p.y][p.x] = null;
            WKSprite.setLocation(convertGridToPhysical(q));  
        }
    }
}
```

The movement works fine but when checking if there is a crate in the way it doesn't work.

I call these two methods before the movement so I can check for a collision when the player actually moves

```
public char getObjectTypeAtPoint(Point p){

    int collision = 0;
    char objectType = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        if (objectList.get(i).getPosition() == p){
            collision = i;
            objectType = objectList.get(collision).getObjectType();

        }
    }
    return objectType;

}

public Objects getObjectAtPoint(Point p){

    int collision = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        if (objectList.get(i).getPosition() == p){
            collision = i;

        }
    }
    return objectList.get(collision);

}
```

The problem is when doing the if test in either of these methods. Even if the point of the object in the array list matches with the given point the code inside the if doesn't happen. The char method just returns 0 and the Objects method always returns an object with a point of 0,0.

I've also tried objectList.get(i).contains() instead of ojectList.get(i).getPosition() but that didn't work either.

Could anyone explain where I'm going wrong or if there's a different way I could do this.

Comment: In Java `==` checks for *reference* equality.  Are you absolutely sure that the point you're checking is the same *instance* of the `Point` object in the list, and not just holding the same coordinates?

Comment: Oh of course. I've changed my code to compare the coordinates of the two points instead of just comparing the points. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your objectList to Point. Objects can hold a variety of data types so you need to be specific if you want it to == another particular data type:

> if ((Point)objectList.get(i).getPosition() == p){    .............. }

at both locations.